# Show and zoom image from center with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a button is clicked I would like for an image to appear, zoom in (scale), zoom out, and then disappear. Here is what I have so far - it does part of what I want. The image does zoom in/out when the button is clicked, but it is doing so from the top left corner rather than the center where I would like.

Secondly, I would like for the image to be hidden until the button is clicked, but that is not working either. I tried setting the display initially to none, and then toggling a class to change the visibility on button click. No joy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I missing some little thing?

Thanks for the help.

```js
//Function that centers in viewport
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
  this.css("position", "absolute");
  this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
  this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
  return this;
}

//Center
$("img").center()

//Zoom in / out
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("img").addClass("visible").center().animate({height: "300px"}, 600).delay(100).animate({height: "100px"},600).removeClass("visible");
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
 /* display:none; */

}

.visible{
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

<img src='http://placeholder.pics/svg/300'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```js
//Function that centers in viewport
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
  this.css("position", "absolute");
  this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
  this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
  return this;
}

$("img").on('animationend', function(e) { 
    $("img").removeClass("big").css({"display": "none"});
  });

//Center
$("img").center()

//Zoom in / out
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("img").addClass("big").css({"display": "initial"});
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.big {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {transform: scale(1,1);}
    50%  {transform: scale(2,2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1,1);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

<img src='http://placeholder.pics/svg/300'>
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it should work for me. It would be nice to have a little explanation though! Never heard of `animationend`

Comment: @showdev well there were a few problems. You can't change the visibility of an element with ".removeClass('visible')" if there is no other default. Also doing these kind of animations in javascript, while technically possible, makes for very confusing a hard to read code. He needed to use the "transform: scale(2,2)" in order to scale the image from the center.

Comment: @blackandorangecat Sorry I was rushing. I should have explained. Basically you can just wait for specific key frame animations to end by using that event listener. You can check for their names in the call back as well.

Comment: @AlexBieg So in, `@keyframes example` the % are the stages, and the transform is the result. It goes from 1, to 2, and then back to 1?

Comment: @blackandorangecat Basically css figures out what it should look like in between each stage of the key frame. We just need to tell it what it needs to  look like at the important points and it will generate the steps in between. In the above code it says start from a scale of 1, go to a scale of 2 half way through, then go back to 1.

Comment: @AlexBieg Learn something new every day - thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This solve your problem:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("img").addClass("visible").center().animate({height: "300px", margin: "-100px"}, 600).delay(100).animate({height: "100px", margin: "0px"},600).removeClass("visible");
});
```

If you change height you should also manage with margin. The easiest way is to count 50% of different between old size and new size, so `(100 - 300) / 2 = -100`

Comment: Thanks, that works well. Any suggestions on how to adjust the visibility?

Comment: I work with this problem now ;-) Give me a minute. The problem is that you can't add class when you put visibility=hidden property.

Comment: Ok - if you sitll want make animation by jQuery - not by css frame you should change your flow. In your example you remove and add class at the same time. That's reason why you can't hide element and show it again. Here is solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783176/change-css-using-jquery-after-animation-is-done

Answer (score 0):

The css position cause this effect. You can refactor this and change the animate like this:

```js
//Function that centers in viewport
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
  this.css("position", "absolute");
  this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
  this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
  return this;
}

//Center
//$("img").center()

//Zoom in / out
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("img").addClass("visible").animate({'zoom': 1.2  }, 600).delay(100);
  $("img").addClass("visible").animate({ 'zoom': 1}, 600);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
 /* display:none; */

}

.visible{
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

<img src='http://placeholder.pics/svg/300'>
```